# Multiple Arithmetic operations in VBA userforms

Tags: vba

I am working on summing up the values of multiple textboxes (A,B,C) into a single textbox (D) and also getting a percentage contribution of the textboxes (A/D , B/D, C/D) and placing the percentage values into other textboxes (E,F,G).

I was succesful in summing up the values using the following code

```
If A.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

If B.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

If C.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

D.Value = CDbl(A.Value) + CDbl(B.Value) + CDbl(C.Value)
```

I am facing difficulty in calculating the percentages of A, B, C into E,F,G boxes.

Would really appreciate if anyone can help me code this stuff out.

Thanks

Comment: VBA---> **V**isual **B**asic for **A**pplications......

Comment: BTW what is the problem you are facing with percentages? Post your efforts...

Comment: You do know how a percentage is calculated, right? Or is the problem how to turn these into a string that can be set to E.Value, etc.?

Comment: I am unable to simultaneously do the percentage operation along with the addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, I think you should be using the [.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822552.aspx) property of the texboxes if you want to set a new value for them for the user to see it.

There is a slight difference between [.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822552.aspx) and [.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193552.aspx) properties, that you can look up on the links I provided. To summarize, [.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822552.aspx) displays the information, and can be different than the [.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193552.aspx) held by the textbox.

What I understand according to what you wrote, is you want to display information for the user based upon input numbers.

Thus, I think the following code should do the trick:

```
' Also, to prevent the updating of every items of the Userfrom 
' and then calculate the percentages, I would suggest using variables
Dim aVal As Single, bVal As Single, cVal As Single, tempVal As Single

If A.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
aVal = CDbl(A.Text)

If B.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
bVal = CDbl(B.Text)

If C.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
cVal = CDbl(C.Text)

tempVal = aVal + bVal + cVal

' Displaying the values in the different textboxes and rounding the percentages
D.Text = tempVal
E.Text = round(aVal / tempVal * 100, 2)
F.Text = round(bVal / tempVal * 100, 2)
G.Text = round(cVal / tempVal * 100, 2)
```

Regards.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered if you think this post fulfills what you asked and upvote if needed.